How To Count Unique Data In Long Range Row
I have data with a row length of around 20,005 and want to count the number of unique data in that row.
Can I using VBA to solve my problem?
I've tried writing the formula =SUM((A5:A20005<>"")/COUNTIF(A5:A20005;A5:A20005&"")) directly in the worksheet but it ends up hang on my computer

Have you tried the UNIQUE function?

=COUNTA(UNIQUE(A5:A20005))

Frequency is useful in older versions of Excel https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273

COUNTA ignores blanks but not empty text (""), so if that's important you can filter out those first =ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A5:A20005,TRIM(A5:A20005) <> "")))

Do you want only counting the unique ones (their total) or also returning these unique? Eventually, how many occurrences pe each. Something working in all Excel versions, not only in 365 and 2019...

Plase, try the next VBA solution. It will work in any Excel version and working mostly in memory it should be very fast. It drops the processed array at once, starting from "L2" (easy to be changed anywhere you consider being more appropriate):
Sub UNIQUEVals()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrUn, i As Long, dict As Object
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet               'use here the sheet you need
 lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A (even bigger then 20,005...)
 
 arr = Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
 
 Set dict = CreateObject("New Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionary
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) + 1            'load the dictionary
 Next i
 Debug.Print "Uneque numbers = " & dict.count 'it returns in Immediate window the number of unique elements
 arrUn = dictTo2DArr(dict)                    'use the function to build the necessary (uniQues) array...
 
 'drop in L2 (easy to be changed) the content of processed array:
 ws.Range("L2").Resize(UBound(arrUn), UBound(arrUn, 2)).Value2 = arrUn 
End Sub

Function dictTo2DArr(dict As Scripting.Dictionary) As Variant
  Dim arr, i As Long
  ReDim arr(1 To dict.count, 1 To 2)
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    arr(i + 1, 1) = dict.keys()(i)  'place the unique keys in the first array column
    arr(i + 1, 2) = dict.Items()(i) 'place the number of occurrences in the second column
  Next i
  dictTo2DArr = arr
End Function

Please, send some feedback after testing it.
I commented the code lines and I hope to be easily understood. If still something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...
